# Lightswitch task on a background thread

Tags: multithreading, background-process, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a lightswitch app which sends an email when a new job is added. I added a sendemail helper class which is called when the record is inserted. 
This works however the interface hangs on save waiting for the email to be sent.
I would like to perform this asychronously so that the user can go on and do his thing while the email sends in the background.

I've tried creating a new thread in the inserted part, hoping it would spin off the thread and then return to the user, but it doesn't work, it is still waiting for the thread to finish.

```
        Thread caseemail = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(newSendmail.generateCaseEmail)); 
        string[] paramsToPass = new String[] { entity.ProjectNumber, entity.CreatedBy, entity.TheProjectClientManagerFixed, entity.ProjectName };
        caseemail.Start(paramsToPass);
```

How should I be doing this?

Comment: I found this guide but I'm still exactly sure how it ensures that this is done a seperate thread, and more importantly, why my code above doesn't do that. http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/2224/Sending-Asynchronous-Emails-Using-LightSwitch-HTML-Client.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end this code works, the errors were from problems access dataworkspaces from the other thread, which is obviously not allowed.

I will leave this here as an example of how to spin off a task into the background from lightswitch, leaving the interface responsive while lightswitch goes away and does something else.